# How to do Flutter Stack Card Scroll Animation?

Tags: flutter, animation, carousel, flutter-animation, flutter-animatedlist

How to make UI and animation like this in Flutter?

[image: Animated ListView]

Comment: You can play with CupertinoPicker

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh Thank you for your answer. Can you give me some reference or example?

Comment: You can use [doc example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPicker-class.html), and use `ìtemExtent` like 200 or based on your need. + Transform may help for non-selectected items.

Comment: Whole card should be scrollable and it should show like card on stack. so will get the result as I want using CupertinoPicker ?

Comment: You can give a try & yes it possible based on knowledge.

Comment: I have tried but not getting what result I want

Comment: you can also look on pub.dev

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255097/discussion-between-hetal-and-md-yeasin-sheikh).